# Как вынести логику запросов React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Хочу выносить всё логику запросов к серверу в отдельную папку, чтобы не загромождать компонент. Но не могу представить как это нужно сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Не получается так

Answer (score 0):

Используй стейт менеджер (`Redux toolkit` или `mobX`)
Далее в папке API создаем фунции, которые делают запрос и возвращают ответ. В файле store у тебя будет состояние, которое ты будешь мутировать с помощью функций, которые делают запрос на сервер. Потом достаешь данные из стора, и распределяешь по компонентам.

Comment: погугли про Redux и все станет понятно

Comment: Ну а вот когда я делаю запрос по фильтрам мне получается нужно будет из самих компонентов фильтров диспатчить их состояние в store?

Comment: @AlexanderKomarchev угу, для ассинхронных запросов есть redux thunk (в redux toolkit уже есть встроенный)